# Is there a good way to bring data collection and analysis tools to a non "smart" router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I just setup a new WiFi network with a Netgear Nighthawk R6700. I didn't want to spring the money for an AmpliFi, Google WiFi, Eero or any of those fancier systems because I don't need a mesh network. However, I do really appreciate the tools those systems give you to diagnose the connections of specific devices and see the aggregate network performance. I'm well aware that there are super-advanced tools designed for this but the ones I've found are mostly designed for an enterprise environment and are consequently expensive, hard to setup, provide too much information or all of the above.

**Is there a relatively easy way (I'm fine getting my hands metaphorically dirty but this is a casual project - I'm not investing a ton of time or money) to get statistics on individual devices and the aggregate network performances without purchasing more hardware?** Bonus points if your solution has an attractive GUI that makes life easier.

Comment: Its possible to point MRTG at some of the third party firmwares. That'd probably be around the ballpark you want.

Comment: Does said router have support for SNMP? That would be your best bet.

Comment: Have you looked at putting DD-WRT on it? It will get you a good part of the way there for free and using a web interface.